# "Et tu, Brute?"

Tags: idiom, latin-to-english-translation, gaius-iulius-caesar

### "Et tu, Brute?"

Julius Caesar's last words; according to William Shakespeare's play of the same name.

There seems to be a difference of opinion regarding the exact translation and thus, too, perhaps, the true meaning of the phrase.

What is the exact, literal translation of the aforementioned phrase? What are other, possible meanings?

Feel free to also include your own interpretation, if you wish to do so.

Comment: Why do you say that there is a difference of opinion as to the translation? A reference to the actual people who hold these opinions would be helpful. As it is, I'm wondering why you haven't just looked up each individual word in a dictionary if you only want the literal meaning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a translation question that doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen as, I believe, we've come a long way in treating questions like these. It's not a perfect question, but it didn't deserve the treatment it got, in my opinion (though I am aware of the context in which it did get this treatment).

Comment: @C.M.Weimer: I think I might agree. Finding a good, step-by-step translation, with alternative translations, too, could be useful to future readers at large. While the question itself is perhaps too simple for a Latinist, I think there is room for more interesting information in a future answer, such as about the historic background or the context. But it's still not a very good question, without mentioning what the "different opinions" are that the OP says exist. Still, I think it's on topic, but just not very high quality. A low score but an open state might be the most appropriate?

Comment: In general, I think "low quality" should generally be indicated by a low score, not by a closing—unless the quality is really too low to lead to anything useful or interesting.

Comment: @Cerberus My thoughts exactly.

Comment: For those downvoting now - is it possible to get a reason why this is a bad question? Let's pretend the OP included two different translations, what else would need fixing?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Well, thanks; I agree. And no, it's not a perfect question, nor am I a perfect person. Sometimes I would struggle to communicate, articulate, or otherwise express a particular thought or idea; as well as I might like. To answer some criticisms: Yes, I have used a dictionary. Yes, there seem to be a myriad of different interpretations, that I've encountered over the years, before I even developed an interest in etymology and ancient languages. No, I haven't prepared a collection, or list of sources to provide you with. It's simply something I have noticed/observed over the years.

Comment: @Cerberus *• "..a good, step-by-step translation, with alternative translations, too, could be useful to future readers at large."* *• "..there is room for more interesting information in a future answer, such as about the historic background or the context."* My thoughts exactly.

Comment: @Everybody If you see a question that could be improved; you're more than welcome to do so. In fact, please do. If you make an edit, and it's no good, the worst that can happen is: ¹It won't get approved, ²it will get rolled back, ³it will get re-edited.. Or: *You could improve the question, and contribute to the collective quality of the site's content. Or: †You can down-vote, or ‡Vote to close; make no improvements.

Comment: @tjt263 I fully understand all that. And posting a question shouldn't be made into a lot of work. This website is supposed to be fun! However, when a question immediately calls up another question, one which only the original poster could answer, that is unfortunate. I don't think you would be expected to produce a list or investigate the issue yourself. But you say "there seems to be a difference of opinion". Don't you have a vague recollection of this difference, which you could write down in one or two sentences? No need for quotations or sources (although they would most welcome).

Comment: I don't know, It comes up fairly frequently in movies and television, etc. Also in general conversation, and so on. Check Nick's answer for some of the more prevalent, basic variations that I'm sure I've seen. He's also provided the literal translation for each individual word. Although, direct translation like that rarely captures the entire essence, context, or subtle nuances of what's been said. But then again, it's likely pure fiction in this instance anyway. And while Shakespeare was evidently well versed in English, I don't actually know how proficient he was with Latin, if at all.

Comment: I think Shakespeare had enough Latin to understand the thrust (pun intended) of Caesar's words, in "*Et tu, Brute?* Then fall, Caesar." which I would give the quick lit crit gloss of meaning - **If even Brutus, whom I love as a son, has turned against me, then it is time to die! "**

Answer (score 16):

Well, without too much knowledge of any deeper, ulterior meanings to the phrase, I can certainly provide and analyze the literal translation for you:

> And you, Brutus?

- *et* → a simple conjunction
- *tu* → vocative, singular case of the second-person pronoun
- *Brute* → vocative, singular case of the proper noun *Brutus* (2nd declension).

Alternative, fairly literal translations:

> Even you, Brutus?
>   You too, Brutus?

Answer (score 16):

Suetonius, in his work *Vita Divi Iuli*, reports the last words of Caesar being Greek καὶ σὺ τέκνον; which is the original source of Shakespeare's line, translated into Latin fairly literally:

- the conjunction καὶ becomes its equivalent *et*;
- the pronoun σὺ becomes its equivalent *tu*,
- [τέκνον](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dte%2Fknon) "child" is replaced by M. Iunius Brutus's own *cognomen*.

An alternative Latin translation, familiar to readers of *Astérix*, is the similar *Tu quoque, fili*: here τέκνον is translated by the equivalent *filius*, but the conjunction *et* "and, too" becomes *quoque* "as well, too, even."

In any case, the meaning is simple: Caesar was chastising Brutus for being among the conspirators, that he expected better from him. "Even you, son?" or "You, too, Brutus?" are standard renderings in English. Because of the simplicity of the phrase, it is rather straightforward to interpret and difficult to ascribe variant readings.

Answer (score 5):

It has already been pointed out that Suetonius reported the words "καὶ σύ, τέκνον" as Caesar's last, and that these are the ultimate origin of Shakespeare's "Et tu, Brute?" (though it seems to be Richard Edes who first coined the Latin phrase, in his 1582 Latin-language play *Caesar Interfectes*, seventeen years before Shakespeare's *Julius Caesar*).
The literal meaning is clear, but for the sake of completeness I want to mention the other interpretation, which has become somewhat popular in recent years, especially since Kathryn Tempest drew attention to it in her 2017 book *Brutus: The Noble Conspirator*.

Apparently the archaeologist James Russell pointed out, in a 1980 article that I haven't been able to track down, that the words "ΚΑΙ ϹΥ" (that is, "καὶ σύ" in caps with a lunate sigma) frequently appear on curse tablets, mosaics, and other forms of art, often in an apotropaic capacity. Here, for instance, is a prominent 2nd-century example from the House of the Evil Eye in Antioch-on-the-Orontes, which shows the Evil Eye being attacked by animals and weapons with the words:

[image: kai su, evil eye]

In this light, Caesar's last words possibly weren't a pathetic disbelieving "even you, son?", but rather a defiant (in Tempest's words) "See you in hell, punk".

The advantage of this view is that the preëxistence of "καὶ σύ" as a formula also provides an explanation for why Caesar would switch to Greek for no apparent reason—educated Romans of the era knew Greek, obviously, but they still spoke Latin in their day-to-day lives.
I don't know if this hypothesis has quite reached mainstream level yet, but I see no obvious problems with it, and it's not surprising it would largely have been missed so far.

Comment: Russell adds that the phrase, which does survive on a mosaic, was probably more fully καὶ σύ ἔρρε, which was shortened since it was so familiar. Interesting idea. I hadn't heard this before (or came across this article before now, probably because it was buried in an edited volume and not published separately in a journal?).

Comment: Seems a bit strange to add τέκνον when you're telling someone to go to hell, though.

Comment: Russell, J. (1980), ‘Julius Caesar’s Last Words: A Reinterpretation’, in B. Marshall (ed.), Vindex Humanitatis. Essays in Honour of John Huntly Bishop. Armidale, 123-128

Comment: You may also want to read Arnaud, Pascal. "«Toi Aussi, Mon Fils, Tu Mangeras Ta Part De Notre Pouvoir» — Brutus Le Tyran ?" Latomus 57, no. 1 (1998): 61-71. http://www.jstor.org/stable/41538208.